# Change wordpress collapsed menu name

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress Twenty Sixteen to build a website. When I open the website in a tablet, it will show a collapsed menu as shown. How can I change the name "Menu" to other words else?

[image: Menu Name]

Thanks for any kind help.

Comment: Can you please share your website link. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1** Login to your website Cpanel or local host what you are using currently.

**Step 2** Open you WordPress directory wp-content-> themes->twintlysexteen->header.php

**Step 3** In your header.php find the class="menu-toggle"  which will look like below

```
<button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></button>
```

**Step 4** change the word menu instead what you want to use I have used SOMETHING ELSE. Look at the screenshot http://prntscr.com/fkrz5z

Answer (score 1):

That's great that you are starting to customize Wordpress!   I would start by searching the Wordpress Forums first before you come here.  Twenty Sixteen has good help at the TwentySixteen forum, linked here: https://wordpress.org/support/theme/twentysixteen

However, to answer your question...  You need to change the button tag: with `id="menu-toggle"`.  To do this you need to customize the theme, which is best done using a child theme: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

The customization will occur in the following line of the file `header.php`:

```
<button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></button>
```

In the above code, the string: `'Menu'` refers to the string that is the text displayed that you want to change, and you just edit that string to be the text you want, and save your file.  Edits can be done in Wordpress UI editor or through accessing your files in another way.  If you edit `header.php` be sure to do it in a child theme as suggested above, or else when you update your theme, you will lose all your customizations.